# Android studio application launching

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android studio and installed successfully into my windows 8 lap. I am not able to open the Android studio application. can any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer:
http://tools.android.com/knownissues

most of the cases is haven't setup JAVA_HOME